# Fire events in one class subscribed from another

Tags: c++, algorithm, events

I have a class `AwesomeMousePointer` that has some function to start playing animations on the mouse:

```
class AwesomeMousePointer{
void startAnimat();
void stopAnimat();
};
```

I have another object to which I have given the responsibility of figuring out whether the mouse anims should start or not (this is based on the internal hit testing on the object, for eg: if the mouse is inside the object for a specific time)

```
class SomeShape(){
Event<MouseArgs> startAnim
Event<bool> interrutptAnim
bool hitTest(int x, int y);

//Inside some loop function, check if the mouse is inside the object
if(hitTest(mouseXPos, mouseYPos)){
//if the mouse if inside for x time
NotiftyEvent(startAnim, MouseArgs);
}
else{
//mouse left the object
NotifyEvent(interruptAnim, false);
}
```

Now, again inside my `AwesomeMousePointer`, I'll add listeners for the events i.e

```
AddListener(SomeShape::startAnim, &AwesomeMousePointer::startAnim);
AddListener(SomeShape::interruptAnim, &AweseommousePointer::interruptAnim);
```

The single event system by using `NotifyEvent` and `AddListener` are working correctly in short different example I tried. Now inside this application of mine, I have a lot of the objects of `SomeShape` and a single `AwesomeMousePointer`. My question is if the above logic for the anims will work or should I explicitly pass the `SomeShape` object explicitly to subscribe to their events, in which things would become a bit difficult.

For eg:

```
AddListener(shapeObject1.startAnim, &AwesomeMousePointer::startAnimat);
AddListener(shapeObject2.startAnim, &AwesomeMousePointer::startAnimat);
AddListener(shapeObject3.startAnim, &AwesomeMousePointer::startAnimat);
```

**OR**

```
AddListener(SomeShape::startAnim, &AwesomeMousePointer::startAnimat);
```

Will the second one from the above work out? If not, how will that be done without explicitly passing the object since that makes the unclear and `ShapeObjects` shouldn't be inside the `MousePointer`.

Will this work if I make the events inside `SomeShape` as static?

```
static Event<MouseArgs> startAnim
static Event<bool> interrutptAnim
```

Comment: what's your `Event` class, what does `AddListener` do?

Comment: @Philipp: I am using `Poco` framework to use the `Event` and `AddListener` which here looks quite similar to C#. `Event` and `AddLister` are basically interited classes from `Poco::Event` and `Poco::delegate`

Answer (score 0):

You say that you don't want to have coupling between the senders and targets. In this case, usage of Poco events is not appropriate. According to http://pocoproject.org/slides/090-NotificationsEvents.pdf, you should use Notifications instead of Events, because your senders and targets do not need to know each other then.